# Kendo Ui List View

Tags: kendo-ui, angular-kendo, kendo-listview

I am new to kendo ui mobile wanted to know why I am getting this specific error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'useNativeScrolling' of undefined**

The code in the view is as follows:

```html
   <ul kendo-mobile-list-view
    k-data-source="xyz.list"
    k-template="xyz.Template"
    k-on-click="xyz.previewList(kendoEvent)"
    k-use-native-scrolling="true"
    data-endless-scroll="true"
    ></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug we introduced in one of our releases - please try upgrading to the current one (Q1 2014 SP1).

Comment: i am using this version Kendo UI v2014.1.416 should i downgrade?

Comment: Anything after the closing of this issue will do. 

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/pull/36

Answer (score 0):

Add the latest kendo cdn.

Add this to your project.

```
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

I solved this problem with this latest cdn